# In unit tests, do we test Super classes too?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I have a situation where class under test has a method which does `return super.delete(obj);` so while writing unit tests with Junit & Jmockit, should I mock return value of `return super.delete(obj);` or keep going up above the hierarchy? Actually, this super call keeps going up to three four levels in inheritance hierarchy. I am just confused if it still remains a unit test if I step into super classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mock that call.  The superclass behavior is (should be) part of the behavior under test when you test a subclass.

Comment: While I agree that I would not mock a call to `super.`, if you are having problems testing it because it goes down to far, it might be a sign of suboptimal code.

Comment: While I also agree that's *best* not to mock that call, this decision comes down to how strict you want to make your *unit* tests. If you're trying to write an [isolated/solitary unit test](http://blog.jayfields.com/2014/07/solitary-unit-test.html), then that call should be mocked, since the base class is not part of the unit under test. If, however, you are going by a [less strict definition of "unit test"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html), then that call would *not* be mocked.